# How to stop an image link continuing to link adjacent text from a shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, links

I want to keep an image link to just the image, but it runs on to the adjacent text. I have an image that I attached a link to and made it into a shortcode:

```
function data_integrity(){
return '<a target="_blank" href="https://openforestry.org/validity-integrity"> <img style="float: right; margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;" src="https://openforestry.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/data_integrity.png" </a>';
}
add_shortcode('shield', 'data_integrity');
```

I'm adding it to posts via the shortcode [shield]. However, whatever text comes after that shortcode is also linked to the same page as the image. How can I force an end to the link in the shortcode or in the post content? Here's an example where the text under the Summary heading is also linked, but I don't want it to be. [Sample of run-on link from image](https://openforestry.org/iufro-2017-garfinkel/)

I've tried to wrap the shortcode in a div, but that did nothing - the link continues to run into the adjacent text.

The post content is currently:

```
[shield] Michele Garfinkel of the European Molecular Biology Organization...
```

I want to keep the layout where the image and text are aligned, but break the HTML link so that the text is just plaintext.

Comment: You forgot the `</a>`!

Comment: Right! Added it, still running over.

Comment: Now you've forgotten to close your image tag: `return '<a target="_blank" href="[...]"> <img style="[...]" src="[...]" </a>';` should be `return '<a target="_blank" href="[...]"> <img style="[...]" src="[...]"> </a>';`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the image tag as well...

```
return '<a target="_blank" href="https://openforestry.org/validity-integrity"> <img style="float: right; margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;" src="https://openforestry.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/data_integrity.png"> </a>';
```